# How to create shell script that compares File modification Time and current time on Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I know I can use `date +%s` and `stat` in Linux system.

But as Solaris does not support those format or command for epoch, 
how can I create a shellscript to compare file modification time and current time ?

modification file time should be within 10 min comparing to current time.

```
[ShellScript]

Current_Time=
Modification_Time=

Compare = Current_Time - Modification_time

if ["$Compare" -gt 600]; then
Echo "there is no find found within 10 min"
else
Echo "Found the file"
if
```

Comment: the `date` cmd in `/usr/xpg4/bin` has extra features that may make your task much easier, but I haven't had access to Solaris in 6 yrs, so I might be mistaken. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if `somefile` was modified in the last ten minutes, you can run this command:

```
file=somefile
if [ -n $(find . -name $file -mmin +10 2>/dev/null) ]; then
    echo " $file was just modified"
else
    echo " $file stayed unchanged"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Find command should solve your problem, did you give a try?

```
$ find . -mmin 10 -print
```

-mmin n (modification time in minutes)